# what to use to get scrolling feature in Instagram and Tinder iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

[image: scrolling in tinder app]

I am developing an app, I am new to iOS, what UI to use to get scrolling feature in the tinder app ? we can scroll left or right to browse between the profiles in the following screen shots, Instagram also has the same feature scrolling left and right, I would appreciate your time to answer this

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one approach to do that:

You could use a simple `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`

In the ViewController:

```
let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
swipe.direction = .left 
swipe.addTarget(target: self, action: #selector(someMethod:))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

In the `someMethod:` function you could change the model of your ViewController or you could show an entirely new one. Whatever you prefer.

You could use a `UIPageViewController` where you would put in all the different `UIViewController` that should get swiped through
[Here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjr4ebUg77QAhXsK8AKHb4KA3QQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fspin.atomicobject.com%2F2015%2F12%2F23%2Fswift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial%2F&usg=AFQjCNFLWwZMsbr5crZZsFsU5kEwsyA7AA&sig2=h_QowIsOpHA70skzVbLTIg&bvm=bv.139782543,d.bGg) is a great tutorial on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `UICollectionView` for horizontal scrolling and a `UITableView` for vertical scrolling inside your main `UIViewController`. Add the `UICollectionView` to the top of the `UIViewController` and `UITableView` below it.